# sorting on column name in stacked class Angular 9 TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular9, columnsorting

I have a table created by a collection of TableColumns. Each column is sortable however the data that populates the columns come from a class with multiple other classes inside it.

for example:

```
    new TableColumn({
    name: 'irsNumber',
    calculate: true,
    visible: true,
    filterable: true,
    filterHeaderLabel: 'Importer IRS #',
    type: 'auto',
    route: `${environment.apiAltRoot}${environment.getExportFilterSearch}getExporterIRSNumber?value={item}`,
    fieldName: 'value',
    displayName: 'value', // what to display in dropdown
    headerValue: (element: any) => 'Importer IRS #',
    cellValue: (element: ImportsModel) => `${element.form7501.irsNumber}`,
  }),
```

my data class or 'element' is this:

```
    export class ImportsModel extends BaseModel {
      id: string;
      form7501: Form7501;
     }
```

In this TableColumn the data 'element.form7501.irsNumber' comes from the form7501 class inside the main class 'element' (data class).

I am trying to sort on this column but inside my current sort method I am doing this:

```
     applySort(data: any[], sort: TableSort): any[] {
       if (this.config.sortBy && this.config.sortBy.columnName) {
       console.log(`--- Applying Sort ---`, this.config.sortBy);

       // sort.columnName is 'irsNumber'
       return data.sort((n1, n2) => {
         if (n1[sort.columnName] > n2[sort.columnName]) {
           return 1;
         }
         if (n1[sort.columnName] < n2[sort.columnName]) {
           return -1;
         }

         return 0;
       });
      }
    }
```

since it is sorting by column name ('irsNumber') but it is looking at the data column names it appears it can't find 'irsNumber' because inside the data class it is 'form7501.irsNumber'.

It seems that, if I am thinking about this correctly, that the code in the applySort() and at least for columns like this, the code should be n1.form7501[sort.columnName] in order for it to find it.

Right now nothing happens and the applySort() returns a 0(zero).

I guess am I thinking about this correctly and if not what would be the appropriate way to get my fields like IrsNumber to sort?

NOTE: I have other columns that are on the main class and they sort fine, its only those that are within other classes in my main class.

Comment: you can try comparing `n1.form7501[sort.columnName]` if its not a common function.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @DurgeshPal, I had tried that already and nothing sorted.